# passing objects in mvp arch

Tags: java, android, mvp, android-mvp

I work with MVP Architecture I get information through an API. In the MODEL LEVEL, I have List I want to pass this List into PRESENTER LEVEL.

When I create a function to resolve this issue I got an error message "NULL ERROR"

Here is my code :

```
package com.example.lenovo.myapplication.Model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class CountryModel {

    private String City;
    private String Country;
    private String Degree;

    @SerializedName("posts")

    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }

    public String getDegree() {
        return Degree;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        City = city;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        Country = country;
    }

    public void setDegree(String degree) {
        Degree = degree;
    }

    public class ResultModel {

        List<CountryModel> posts;

        public List<CountryModel> getCountryModels() {
            return posts;
        }

        public void setCountryModels(List<CountryModel> countryModels) {
            this.posts = countryModels;

        }
    }
}
```

interface method

```
public CountryModel Get_Wather_Informations(int position);
```

model code

```
 connection.enqueue(new Callback<CountryModel.ResultModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CountryModel.ResultModel> call, Response<CountryModel.ResultModel> response) {


            countryModels = response.body().getCountryModels();

            for (int i = 0; i < countryModels.size(); i++) {

                CountryModel ye = new CountryModel();
                ye.setCountry(countryModels.get(i).getCountry());
                ye.setCity(countryModels.get(i).getCity());
                ye.setDegree(countryModels.get(i).getDegree());
                ARRAYS.add(ye);
                Log.e("array size ", String.valueOf(ARRAYS.size()));
              //  Log.e("Size", String.valueOf(arrayList.size()));


            }


 @Override
public CountryModel Get_Wather_Informations(int position) {
    return countryModels.get(position);
}
```

When I try to get an object from this list ( PRESENTER LAYER ) I get a null!

```
CountryModel COUNTRY_OBJ = new CountryModel();
COUNTRY_OBJ = MODEL.Get_Wather_Informations(0);
```

Comment: Post full error stack & code pls

Comment: what line causes the error? and please post the stack trace. Additionally, it appears you are not including the full code.